# What object is suitble to represent 30 minutes in iOS

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I would like to present a ticking timer that goes back. I have the `NSTimer` functions set already and I bumped on this simple unexpected question. How do I get the 30 minuted from?
I know how to get a certain date, like `[NSDate date]`. But how do I get minutes? 
I need to have an object that holds 30 minutes. And every second to subtract a second from it. So I could show the timer to the user.

30:00

29:59

29:58

....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"30 minutes" is not a *date*, but a *time interval*, and the appropriate type is
`NSTimeInterval`, which is defined as

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

and represents a time interval in seconds. You can easily convert that to minutes/seconds
for display:

```
NSTimeInterval remainingTime = ...; // e.g. 30*60 for 30 minutes
int minutes = (int)remainingTime / 60;
int seconds = (int)remainingTime % 60;
```